# Is there a way to override MinLengthValidator error message in Django 1.7?

Tags: django

I am using a text box to get the mobile number from the user.

models.py

```
mobile = models.CharField(max_length=14, validators=[MinLengthValidator(10)])
```

The default error message looks like:

```
Ensure this value has at least 10 characters (it has 2).
```

How can I override the error message?

Answer (score 2):

Django has [added](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#minlengthvalidator) a `message` parameter, so in the future you'll be able to say `validators=[MinLengthValidator(10, message='My message')]`.

For now, the simplest thing is probably just to instantiate the class and set the message attribute.

```
my_validator = MinLengthValidator(10)
my_validator.message = 'My message'
```

If you don't like relying on undocumented code, then just write the validator yourself, it will only be a few lines.

Answer (score 0):

Yes by removing the validator and writing your own. You can do this by [overriding your form's `clean` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other).

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(YourForm, self).clean()
    mobile = cleaned_data.get("mobile")

    if len(mobile) < 10:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Your message here.")
```